# Get the oldest datetime value with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mySQL-table

```
CREATE TABLE `products_to_categories` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`,`categories_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The products_id 2085 has three entries because it is in three categories.

```
products_id    categories_id    date_added
2085           204              2013-03-01
2085           143              2013-03-13
2085           86               2013-03-25
```

Actually I have this query to order them by date_added

```
SELECT   categories_id,
         products_id
FROM     products_to_categories
WHERE    categories_id != 0
ORDER BY date_added
```

How do I get the oldest value (in this case 2013-03-01) with a query?

Comment: Do you want to get all products, but get only one row by product, keeping only the oldest rows ?
Or do you only want to get the oldest row of the table where categories_id != 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are entries are date based then you can use `Min` operator

```
SELECT products_id,MIN(date_added) AS OldDate
FROM products_to_categories group by products_id
```

The above query will select the min of date for all products_id..

Comment: @Ronny linsener .Friend have you tried my answer. i think my answer will satisfy your needs.

Comment: Damn, it really works. You're the winner

Comment: @RonnyLinsener it will appreciate me, if you accept my answer and give upvote,if my answer is helpful to you..

Answer (score 3):

Use the aggregate function `MIN`:

```
SELECT MIN(date_added) AS OldestDate
FROM products_to_categories
WHERE products_id = 2085;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb462/1)

---

If you are looking for the oldest date for each product, add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT products_id, MIN(date_added) AS OldestDate
FROM products_to_categories
GROUP BY products_id;
```

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0a49/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the entire row:

```
select ptc.*
from products_to_categories ptc
where products_id = 2085 
order by date_added
limit 1;
```

This will be optimized with an index on `products_to_categories(products_id, date_added)`.

EDIT:

The oldest value for each product:

```
select products_id, min(date_added)
from products_to_categories ptc
group by products_id;
```

Comment: But in my original query I don't point on the products_id. The pid=285 was just an example

Comment: @RonnyLinsener . . . I don't understand what you are looking for.  If you want the oldest record, just remove the `where` statement.  Do you want the oldest value for each product?

Comment: You're right. This is exactly what I'd like to have, the oldest value of each product. [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0a49)

Answer (score 0):

This way you will have the oldest line for each product.

```
SELECT products_id, categories_id, MIN(date_added)
FROM products_to_categories
WHERE categories_id != 0
GROUP BY products_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_added AS OldestDate
FROM products_to_categories
order by OldestDate
limit 1;
```

DEmo : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb462/2